# jQuery error when Firebug is enabled

Tags: jquery, drupal, firebug

When I load my page without Firebug running, all of my JavaScript loads and executes fine. However, if I enable Firebug 2.0.7, the desired behavior fails and the following appears in the console:

```
TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined
    if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) < 7) {
```

That line appears inside a function that controls something called "floating_block behavior" in Drupal:

```
/**
 * Attaches the floating_block behavior.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.blockFloat = function (context) {

  var settings = Drupal.settings.floating_block;

  // This breaks in anything less than IE 7. Prevent it from running.
  if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) < 7) {
    return;
  }

  // If this behaviour is being called as part of processing an ajax callback.
  if (jQuery.isFunction(context.parent)) {
    context = context.parent();
  }
```

If I scroll to the beginning of the JS file, I see this:

```
/*
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 John Resig
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://docs.jquery.com/License
 *
 * Date: 2009-02-19 17:34:21 -0500 (Thu, 19 Feb 2009)
 * Revision: 6246
 */
```

Updating jQuery and/or Drupal is out of the question. Is there anything I can do to prevent this error when Firebug is enabled?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the Floating Block module. I remember this error with the admin menu module when using jquery above 1.9 as jQuery.browser was removed from jQuery. But it seems you are using a jQuery version that should still support it. Are you sure only 1 version of jquery is being loaded?

Comment: Thank you! Turns out version 1.11.1 is running as well.

Comment: So, did 2pha's comment solved your problem? If so, 2pha or you should post it as answer and accept it.